# Prevent macOS Mail from moving the the "next" message after deleting

Tags: macos, mac, email

Is there a "hidden preference" to prevent macOS Mail to shift focus to the "next" message after I delete or move a message? After a moment, that "next" message is automatically marked as read, and I would like to disable that behavior.

Incidentally, how does one find what "hidden preferences" (those set with `defaults write com.apple.mail ...`) apply to Mail, or to any other app?

I'm on macOS 12.6.3.

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the two previous subjects. Those posts are quite old. The "classic layout" option no longer exists, though you can recreate it by resizing the panes of the main window. That's a valid option, if a little inconvenient. I didn't find that Option-Delete was a good option because a) it permanently deletes the message with no possibility to undo, and b) it doesn't apply to moving messages to folder. I haven't tried the Javascript service.